# Seafile “ImportError: No module named Image” After upgrade 3.0 -> 4.2

Tags: centos, python

I recently upgraded our seafile server from 3.0.4 to 4.2.3. All the upgrade scripts went fine.

It's running on CentOS 6.6. But now when I try to start seahub after the upgrade like

```
seahub.sh start-fastcgi 8000
```

I get

```
Starting seahub (fastcgi) at 127.0.0.1:8000 ...
ImportError: No module named Image
```

I have python-imaging installed. But I think I read that you had to replace it with Pillow? What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the server I was working with were using python 2.7, installing packages from yum installed only 2.6 version. Used pip2.7 to install necessary packages.